# Listening for output of Destination from Navigation Component Host

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

Is there a way to listen for output values from nav destinations and let the host decide which the next destination should be? What I understand is that each destination must decide on its own which the next destination should be which couples the destination with the specific flow and doesn't allow us to reuse it in another flow.

I'd like fragments or any kind of other nav destinations to be just like functions - you give them input, they provide you with their output and you decide where to go next.

Comment: The only way to detach the Fragment from its Flow is to create a ViewModel for the Fragment, define an interface in the ViewModel, and inject some flow-dependent implementation of an interface defined in the ViewModel to actually handle these events. However, that implementation should be scoped to a shared NavGraph that represents the flow... Which you can actually get a reference to only with the help of the NavBackStackEntry of the NavGraph.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah, I figured that would be the only way. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid the boilerplate but I guess I can't without code-generation. You can write this comment as an answer, so I can accept it. Btw any idea if I can scope a VM to a nested graph?

Comment: You can definitely scope a VM to a nested graph. See https://github.com/Zhuinden/jetpack-navigation-ftue-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/jetpacknavigationdaggersavedstatehandleftueexperiment/features/registration/CreateLoginCredentialsFragment.kt#L36

Comment: Yeah, I just saw this here as well. Thanks!
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

Navigation does not have any mechanism for plugging in your own business logic - it only provides the lower level building block of `navigate()`, which unconditionally goes to the destination you provide it.

It would be up to you to decide where any logic you need to make the correct `navigate()` call should be (in the fragment itself, in a ViewModel that provides a `NavDirection` instance, in some higher level construct that represents your entire flow stored at [the navigation graph level](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel), etc.).